# Does LocalAlloc with LMEM_FIXED prevent paging

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using the `LocalAlloc` function to allocate some memory, and I noticed the `LMEM_FIXED` flag.
Microsoft states that the `LMEM_FIXED` flag does the following:

> Allocates fixed memory. The return value is a pointer to the memory object.

I was wondering if this meant that the memory could not be paged to the **disk**. What I mean by this is does the `LMEM_FIXED` flag prevent the writing of memory (paging) to the disk?

Comment: No. The "fixed" means that the virtual address won't change, unlike movable memory which can be relocated in the virtual address space.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ahh Ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc), specifically the description for the `uFlags` parameter. You'll find the following:

> `LMEM_MOVEABLE`: [...] This value cannot be combined with `LMEM_FIXED`.

In other words: `LMEM_FIXED` and `LMEM_MOVEABLE` are mutually exclusive. So then, what does `LMEM_MOVEABLE` amount to? It's a hint to the memory manager that allows it to move the backing memory around, e.g. when [LocalReAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localrealloc)'ing memory or compacting the heap<sup>1</sup>.

`LMEM_FIXED` (or [LocalLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-locallock)'ing memory), on the other hand, communicates to the memory manager, that the memory cannot move.

While that may be interesting from a historic perspective, it's of little practical use today. From [Global and Local Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/global-and-local-functions):

> The global and local functions are supported for porting from 16-bit code, or for maintaining source code compatibility with 16-bit Windows. Starting with 32-bit Windows, the global and local functions are implemented as wrapper functions that call the corresponding [heap functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/heap-functions) using a handle to the process's default heap.

I'm not aware of any immediate use case for the local heap functions today. The global heap functions are still used for things like the [clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard), even though the underlying implementation has changed. It does not allocate truly global memory that is shared between processes.

With that out of the way, here is the answer to the question: `LMEM_FIXED` doesn't prevent memory from being paged out to disk. If you need to pin memory into physical RAM you would need to call [VirtualLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtuallock).

---

<sup>1</sup> *[A history of GlobalLock, part 1: The early years](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041104-00/?p=37393) has more information. Although it talks about the global heap, the semantics are the same for the local heap.*